# how to update pg_dump to server version in Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to backup a local database in my laptop (PostGresSQL 9.6 ,PgAdmin3) and I see the following error.

> pg_dump: server version: 9.6.3; pg_dump version: 9.5.5 
>   pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

I've tried some answers on SO, like updating the postgres on homebrew but it threw an error as well.

> Error: postgres not installed

When I checked the contents of postgres application package, I found 2 folders in the versions folder, 9.5 and 9.6. I tried running the pg_dump in the bin folder of both the versions and all I see is this error:

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem and make a backup of my database

Answer (score 8):

Resurfaced when our server got to postgresql `13.8` and locally I was on `12`

Uninstall the old postgresql version and install a new one. Start & stop postgres services too. On Mac:

```
brew install postgresql@13 # install server version or higher
brew services stop postgresql@12 # stop postgres
brew uninstall postgresql@12 # uninstall old version
brew services start postgresql@13 # start newly installed version
```

Double check the version in use: `psql --version`

Get info on postgresql versions installed via brew: `brew info postgresql@13`

Comment: uninstalling the old version specifically did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If using brew on MacOS `brew install postgresql@8.4.4` [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Stop postgres

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

Upgrade with Homebrew

```
brew update
brew upgrade postgresql
```

Check Version:

```
psql --version
> psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this one more helpful than above. It has upgraded the DB without any issue. https://quaran.to/Upgrade-PostgreSQL-from-12-to-13-with-Homebrew

```
brew services stop postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services start postgresql
```